# Unity3D gui form text too small

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, textfield, unityscript

so for my code I am having the user type in their name before they submit their score. However, the form text is really small. The "name" and "submit" won't change. I can change the text inside the textfield where users enter their name though.

Thank you for any insight.

```
private var formNick = ""; 
var pointObject : Transform;
private var formScore = "";
var bigFont: GUIStyle;

var formText = ""; 
var URL = " ";


function OnGUI() {

GUI.Label( Rect ( Screen.width/2 - 20, Screen.height/2, 80, 20), "Name:" ); 
formNick = GUI.TextField ( Rect (Screen.width/2 - 50, Screen.height/2 + 30, 100, 20), formNick,50, bigFont ); //here you will insert the new value to variable formNick

if ( GUI.Button ( Rect (Screen.width/2 - 50, Screen.height/2 + 50, 100, 20) , "Submit Score" ) ){ //just a button
    if(formNick != "")
    {
        Submit();
        enabled = false;
        //Testing

    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Please enter a name");
    }
}


}
function Submit()
{
var form = new WWWForm(); 
formScore = pointObject.GetComponent(pointManager).points.ToString();
form.AddField( "name", formNick );
form.AddField( "score", formScore );

var w = WWW(URL, form);

yield w;

if (w.error != null ) {
    print(w.error); 
} else {
    print("Score Submitted" + formScore);
}
formNick = ""; 
formScore = "";

  Application.LoadLevel("scoreboard");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GUIStyle to change the font size.

```
function OnGUI() {
    var style : GUIStyle = new GUIStyle();
    style.fontSize = 25;
    GUI.Label( Rect ( Screen.width/2 - 20, Screen.height/2, 80, 20), "Name:", style); 
}
```